# How to use short-circuit evaluation in vue method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vuex, short-circuit-evaluation

I'm using vue-cli and vuex and I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
methods: {
filtered() { 
  let vol = this.$store.state.data[1].data.filter(i => i.type === 'vol')[0].measure || 0;
  let weight = this.$store.state.data[1].data.filter(i => i.type === 'weight')[0].measure || 0;
 }
}
```

my current data contains a vol `type` but not a weight so I'd like `let weight` to `= 0`

but I'm getting an error that `Cannot read property 'measure' of undefined`.

Any ideas would be great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `filter()`, use `find()` and store it in a variable. Then check whether the variable contains anything.

```
methods: {
    filtered() {
      let volobj = this.$store.state.data[1].data.find(i => i.type === 'vol')
      let vol = volobj ? volobj.measure : 0;
      let weightobj = this.$store.state.data[1].data.find(i => i.type === 'weight')
      let weight = weightobj ? weightobj.measure : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer :

- `filter()` array helper returns `Array` where as `find()` returns first element of result.
- Set your default value here : `{ measure: 0 }` , If nothing found this will be used as fallback

```
methods: {
    filtered() {
      let vol = (this.$store.state.data[1].data.find(i => i.type === 'vol') || { measure: 0 }).measure
      let weight = (this.$store.state.data[1].data.find(i => i.type === 'weight') || { measure: 0 }).measure
    }
}
```